# How to find out how much memory a program taking

Tags: memory, top

I use htop to watch my processes, but most of services ran are multi threaded, so they are shown on several lines with a % of memory use which in some cases is the same for all, sometimes it varies among them.

Say in the case of Firefox it can list 15 processes each consuming 13% of memory.

Can I know hoc much memory is Firefox, MySQL, some fcgi script or anything is consuming? since the htop output seems misleading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most top implementations have a way to turn the display of threads on or off.

- htop: in the “Setup / Display options” menu, “Hide userlands threads”.
- Linux top: press `H` to toggle the showing of threads (but they're off by default).
- OpenBSD top: press `T` to toggle the showing of threads (but they're off by default).

Note that memory mappings, and hence memory occupation, is a property of a process, so you'll always see the same numbers for every thread in a process. If you see different numbers, it means there are multiple processes.

There's no easy way to find out the total memory consumption of a set of processes because the concept isn't well-defined. Some of the memory may be shared; this happens all the time with shared libraries, and in addition related processes (such as multiple instances of a server) are more likely to use shared memory to exchange data. If you just add the figures, you'll often get a number that's a lot larger than the actual used memory.

Comment: I didn't realize that the process' memory concept isn't well defined, I think that's what makes it all have more sense. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use this: http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ps_mem.py

Comment: why use that? why is it better than the standard tools?

Comment: It counts shared memory only once.